# debug an Xcode project in another project

Tags: ios

In my project a framework developed by my organization is included and working with that framework. To fix one issue, I am planning to take the framework project code and then include into my project and then debug step by step using breakpoints. Is this achievable? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You create a workspace.  add target dependency in your project then normal debugging works

[image]

[image]

Comment: Question 1) What is the use of new workspace, when we have the existing workspace? Also, Question 2) I have imported framework project code to my DummyApp and then added target dependencies for the DummyApp (framework Project resources, Static Library and framework). After doing this, I am not able to import Framework in my DummyApp's ViewController. Any idea?

Comment: 1. In new workspace you can add your .app project as well as .framework password 2)When you add framework or static library as target dependency your framework or library code executed every time. How are you importing your framework? usually import will be like this `#import<fw/fwclass.h>`

Comment: I am trying to import in the same way as you said. But no use.